# Replace text in each element of array via filter

Tags: javascript, filter, replace

```js
let arr = ['hamster', 'cat']

arr = arr.filter(el => el.replace("a", "A"));
console.log(arr);
```

I will get `['hAmster', 'cAt']` (replaced part of text), but it is not works

Comment: you want `map`, not `filter` which is for - well - filtering.

Comment: I think you want to use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of filter; this is not what filter is meant for. Or a regular for-loop.

Comment: @mykaf `forEach()` ignores the return value, so it won't work for this. `map()` is right.

Comment: I had considered `map()`, but it's less confusing, at least to me, when updating the same array you're looping over, to use `forEach()`, which of course, would require additional changes.

Comment: @mykaf - `forEach` won't work with an array of strings because strings are immutable. You could start with an empty array and push the transformed element onto it inside a `forEach` but then that's just a long-winded way of writing `map`, and much less easy to read.